# Help with conceptual vector and matrix related questions.

Tags: matrices, vectors

Are the following statements true or false, and why?

> 1. Vectors $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}$, and $\mathbf{w}$ are linearly
>    independent if the homogeneous equation $c_1 
>    \mathbf{u}+c_2\mathbf{v}+c_3\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{0}$ has no solutions.
> 2. f the columns of an $n\times n$ matrix are linearly independent,
>    then the row reduced matrix has exactly $n$ pivots.
> 3. Vectors that are linearly dependent are always collinear.

So here are my answers and I was wondering if they were right or not. Or if I messed up an explanation or if there is a correct explanation or if I got the answer wrong.

**A) True.** If there are no solutions in the augmented matrix then it means the vectors are linearly independent.

**B) False.** There has to be n-1 or fewer pivots than n, so the matrix is inconsistent (no solutions) Like a bottom row that looks like this: $[0,0,0,1]$

**C) False.** Vectors can be perpendicular to each other.

Comment: All of your answers are wrong. You should really focus on asking one question at a time, and maybe be specific about what your thoughts are and where you are confused. For example, an explanation of why you are not sure if the answer you are giving is right or not, along with some details about what you do or don't understand about linear independence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **False.** There is always the solution $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$.
2. **True.** Row reducing a matrix does not change its rank, which is the same as the dimension of the column space.
3. **Unclear.** Do you mean pairs of vectors? Or sets of vectors? Either way your argument makes no sense.

Comment: I think it means sets of vectors. Thank you for the help so I appreciate it!

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?